# Changing input value via Javascript before form submission? PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Been through a number of questions and nothing seems to work for my case.

Okay so, I have a form with a single input (search) field and a submit button. When the user enters a value (an address in this case) and hits submit, that address value needs to be sent to a JavaScript function which converts it into Longitude and Latitude values, and then these coordinates need to be sent to the destination page instead of the address they input.

Here is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<form name="searchform" action="required/results.php" method="get" id="searchbar" onsubmit="convertToCoords()"> 
    <input type="text" name="input" id="address" placeholder="Search an address or suburb...">
    <input type="submit" class="searchbtn" value="Search"> 
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function convertToCoords() {    
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value; // Get the input address from the textbox

    /* Address to Coordinates conversion (Disregard) */
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {    
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        // Get the Lat. and Long. 
        var searchedLat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var searchedLong = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        // Set address input value to coordinates, then submit form
        document.getElementById('address').value = searchedLat + ',' + searchedLong;
        document.getElementById('searchbar').submit();

    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
    }); 
}
```

**PHP on destination page (for testing)**

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_GET['input'])) {
        echo $_GET['input']; // get value of search input
    }
?>
```

So at the moment what is happening is it is just echoing the address they input, no conversion happens.

I don't know (or care) when the conversion should happen, e.g. whether it should happen before submission or after.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: inplace of using form submit, change it to onCLick() and call a javascript function and change data there and then make a post request to required url.

Comment: To explain your problem, your `convertToCoords` starts an asynchronous request to Google which has not yet returned when the form submits (which is pretty much instantly after the click). Thus you'd have to wait for its return before actually submitting the form (or doing something else with the returned value).

Comment: Hi @lemarc I removed the 'onsubmit' and I added `onclick="convertToCoords()"` into my submit button HTML, and it still does not work. It goes to the next page but it echos the address, not the convert coordinates. Thanks though!

Comment: @christian314159 I have heard that, and feared that was the case. How might you suggest I go about it? Thanks

Comment: @n00bAppDev, you have to remove the form tags and then do it. i.e. after `onclick="convertToCoords()"`, in `convertToCoords()` function, you have to make a post query yourself using javascript.

Comment: @lemarc I removed `onsubmit="convertToCoords()"` from the form tag, and I added `onclick="convertToCoords()"` into the `<input type="submit"...` tag. Is that right?

How do you make a post query in JS?

Comment: @n00bAppDev, http://bit.ly/1mUEue8

Comment: @lemarc I already Googled it... I couldn't find an answer that works in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I made a basic example of how it could work, please see the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5mMtm/1/

The principle is:

- capture the form's submit
- do an ajax call to an API (in your case geocoder) with the data entered
- change form input value and send/submit to own endpoint

I'm using jQuery in the example:

```
$(function(){

    var $form = $('#my-form'), // the form
        $adrInput = $form.find('[name=address]'), // the address input field
        isSearching = false; // a flag to prevent multiple submits

    // on form submit event
    $form.on('submit', function(e){
        // Prevent submit event
        e.preventDefault();

        // Don't start another search while
        // other is still going
        if( isSearching ){ return; }
        isSearching = true;

        // Start query to google
        getAddressFromGoogle();
    });


    function getAddressFromGoogle(){

        var address = $adrInput.val();

        // Get lat/lng value and then do something with it
        getLatLng( address, function( lat, lng ){
            $adrInput.val( lat + ',' + lng );   
        });
    }


    // this function takes two parameters
    // the address as a string from the input field
    // and a callback it will invoke with the results
    // when it's done
    function getLatLng( address, callback ){    

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 

        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function( results, status ){    
            if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ){

                // Get the Lat. and Long. 
                var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                    lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                // Pass latLng to callback function
                if( typeof callback === 'function' ){
                    callback.apply( null, [ lat, lng ]);
                }
            }
            else {
              alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        }); 
    }

});
```

Comment: Okay, I will try implement this now and let you know how I go thanks!

One question though, where abouts do I place this Ajax code, and how do I call upon it?

Comment: Where I have the `setTimeout` function in my example, replace this with your geocoder code. The `setTimeout` is just a placeholder for some asynchronous function.

Comment: I did what you said and it seems that it is not running any of the javascript/jQuery. I tried debugging it in Firefox and when I put a break point on the e.preventDefault, it never gets run.

Am I right in saying I just copy your code into my js file and amend my own code?

Here is the fiddle of my current code, thanks:  http://jsfiddle.net/5mMtm/

Comment: I think you didn't actually save/update the fiddle, but I created a new one that is fully functional now: http://jsfiddle.net/5mMtm/1/ (I will update my answer as well)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do an event.preventDefault() at the begining. It will prevent the submit made by the "browser" ... so you will be able to do your own submit.

Here is a simplified version of your code:

Javascript:

```
var convertToCoords = function() {    
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('address').value = "test";
    document.getElementById('searchbar').submit();
};
```

Html:

```
<form name="searchform" action="required/results.php" method="get" id="searchbar" onsubmit="convertToCoords()"> 
    <input type="text" name="input" id="address" placeholder="Search an address or suburb...">
    <input type="submit" class="searchbtn" value="Search"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input, although this does not work. It simply does nothing when I press the submit button. Although, weirdly enough, when I try it in Firefox it goes to the destination page, although it does not run the Javascript.